# evaluate $\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Need help evaluating

$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

I want to know why my working out is illegitimate. It looks illegal. Im just not sure by what mechanism it is illegal.[image]

Comment: $\sec \theta \ d\theta \neq dx$ in the third line

Comment: haha funny, thanks.

Comment: should I delete this post I dont know how to close it

Comment: notice that $2+1 =3$ this might seem trivial but it is the key to the solution $$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\int \frac{x^{2} x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$ let $u=x^2$

Comment: @azif00 wait but then could you give a hint for what to do next after the 2nd line? I can make a substitution using sqrt (x) but I want to try using a trigonometric substitution...is that possible?

Comment: Trig substitution is not your friend here. Instead $$\int \frac{x(x^2+1-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx = \int x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$$ Both of these two terms have simple antiderivatives.

Comment: I will argue that trig substitution seems a bit more natural here, but the u-sub works too. The method by @NinadMunshi feels a bit "magical" and would take many students a while to spot.

Comment: @SeanRoberson what trig substitution? should I let x=sec0 since the derivative will be sec0tan0?

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047713/how-to-evaluate-int-fracx3-sqrt-x21dx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to approach it using hyperbolic functions:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{x^{3}}{\sqrt{x^{2} + 1}}\mathrm{d}x & = \int\frac{\sinh^{3}(u)}{\sqrt{\sinh^{2}(u) + 1}}\mathrm{d}(\sinh(u))\\
& = \int\sinh^{3}(u)\mathrm{d}u\\
& = \int\sinh^{2}(u)\sinh(u)\mathrm{d}u\\
& = \int(\cosh^{2}(u) - 1)\sinh(u)\mathrm{d}u\\
& = \int(\cosh^{2}(u) - 1)\mathrm{d}(\cosh(u))\\
& = \int(v^{2} - 1)\mathrm{d}v\\
& = \frac{v^{3}}{3} - v + C\\
& = \frac{\cosh^{3}(u)}{3} - \cosh(u) + C\\
& = \frac{(x^{2} + 1)^{3/2}}{3} - \sqrt{x^{2} + 1} + C
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The penultimate equality is wrong. Instead, in
$$\int \sec \theta \tan^3 \theta \,d\theta $$ the powers of both $\tan \theta$ and $\sec \theta$ are odd, which suggests the substitution $v = \sec \theta, dv = \sec \theta \tan \theta \,d\theta,$ giving
$$\int \sec \theta \tan^3 \theta \,d\theta = \int (\sec^2 \theta - 1) \sec \theta \tan \theta \,d\theta = \int (v^2 - 1) \,dv = \frac{1}{3} v^3 - v + C .$$

Composing the substitutions $x \rightsquigarrow \theta \rightsquigarrow v$ gives another possible choice, $v = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}, dv = \frac{x \,dx}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$.

**Remark** There's an arguably easier method to evaluate the original integral that also avoids trigonometric/hyperbolic substitutions. Substituting $w = x^2 + 1$, $dw = 2 x \,dx$, gives
$$\int \frac{x^3 \,dx}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}} = \frac12 \int \frac{(w - 1) \,dw}{\sqrt w} = \frac12 \int \left(\sqrt w - \frac1{\sqrt w}\right) = \frac13 w^{3/2} - \sqrt w + C .$$

More generally, given an integral of the form
$$\int x^{2 m + 1} f(x^2 + a) \,dx,$$
where $m$ is an integer, the substitution $w = x^2 + a$, $dw = 2 x \,dx$ transforms the integral to
$$\frac12 \int (w - a)^m f(w) \,dw .$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

let $x=\tan(u)$

so $dx=\sec^2(u)du$

so the integral is now
$$ \int \frac{\tan^3(u)(\sec^2(u))du}{\sec(u)} $$

which is the same as $$ \int \tan^3(u)\sec(u)du$$
or
$$\int ((\sec^2(u)-1)(\sec(u)\tan(u))du$$

now sub $\sec(u)=t$ and you should get your answer. Please ping me If I've made any errors

Comment: In the last display equation there's a parenthesis missing to the right of $\sec^2 (u)$. (Also, using `\sec` instead of `sec` produces a roman $\sec$ as is traditional, instead of an italicized $sec$.)

Answer (score 1):

**Integration by parts**
$$
\begin{aligned} \int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\, d x&=\int x^2 d\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}\right) \\& =x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1}-\int \sqrt{x^2+1} \,d\left(x^2+1\right) \\
& =x^2 \sqrt{x^2+1}-\frac 32\left(x^2+1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+C\\
& =\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{3}\left(x^2-2\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$